# Having problems with using .Scroll in Elasticsearch Nest 5.5

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I wanted to loop and scroll thru the data using the scrollid then
I've upgraded to NEST 5.5 and trying to remediate this block of code:

```
scrollGetSearch = client.Raw.ScrollGet(scrollId, x => x
    .AddQueryString("scroll", "1m")
    .AddQueryString("size", "1000"));
```

Tried using using `.Scroll` but can't find the correct arguments for the scroll method:

```
scrollGetSearch = client.Scroll("1m",scrollId)
```

Getting the Error

> The type arguments for method 'Nest.ElasticClient.Scroll(Nest.Time,
>   string, System.Func,Nest.IScrollRequest>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first request uses the low level client, Elasticsearch.Net, whilst the second request uses the high level client.

To perform the same low level request in NEST 5.x would be

```
ElasticsearchResponse<T> lowLevelScrollResponse = client.LowLevel.ScrollGet<T>(x => x
    .AddQueryString("scroll_id", scrollId)
    .AddQueryString("scroll", "1m"));
```

The generic parameter `T` should be the type that the body of the response should be deserialized into e.g. `string`, `byte[]` or because you're using the low level client exposed on the high level client, the high level response, `SearchResponse<TDocument>`, where `TDocument` is the type that each `_source` should be deserialized into. There's no need to specify `size` on a scroll request as the size is configured on the first scroll call to `_search` endpoint.

To perform the same search with the high level client

```
ISearchResponse<T> scrollResponse = client.Scroll<T>("1m", scrollId);
```

Comment: What is the difference between high level and low level client?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on the clients which covers the differences: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index.html